# alerts in else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert, conditional-statements

Why won't this code work correctly?  If someone selects something with an id of of '1599' then an alert will show "$1,599.00". If the id does not match, then the alert should show "$1,499.00".  But it doesn't.  Could someone help me figure this out?

thanks

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPrice(){

var a = document.getElementById();

    if (a == "1599"){
        alert("$1,599.00");
    }
    else {
        alert("$1,499.00");
    }
}
<body>
<div class="hc_right">
            <input type="button" class="spc" value="Price" onclick="showPrice()" />
            <p class="price" id="1599">$1,599.00</p>
        </div>

        <div class="hc_right">
            <input type="button" class="spc" value="Price" onclick="showPrice()" />
            <p class="price" id="1499">$1,499.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect from this call: `a = document.getElementById();` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to let `showPrice` know which element you want to show the alert for. Right now, you're not actually selecting anything with the `document.getElementById` (`a` will be either `null` or `undefined` at this point).

There are a bunch of different ways to go about doing this, but to keep it close to your current implementation, I might do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hc_right">
        <input type="button" class="spc" value="Price" onclick="showPrice(1599)" />
        <p class="price" id="1599">$1,599.00</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hc_right">
        <input type="button" class="spc" value="Price" onclick="showPrice(1499)" />
        <p class="price" id="1499">$1,499.00</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showPrice(a){

    if (a == "1599"){
        alert("$1,599.00");
    }
    else {
        alert("$1,499.00");
    }
    return false;
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6QrVW/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you will see the issue if you add an
    alert(a);
before the if(...) -- My guess is that you aren't getting the value you expect in there.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementById()` method takes a parameter of the ID to look for. Something like:

```
document.getElementById("1599")
```

and will return the document element that has that ID. Not sure what it will return when no parameter is passed.

Comment: `Not sure what it will return when no parameter is passed`. [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) can be helpful. Not providing a parameter is an error so the return value is browser dependent - Firefox throws an error, IE returns `null`. :-)